# List Sharepoint directory contents using AD authentication and python

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So I trying to come up with a script to check and report files from my sharepoint according to some criteria. I need however authenticate using the company Active Directory.

I have done some research and all I've found seem far too advanced for what I intend and would prefer not to spend the whole time learning [django custom auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/). [Haufe.sharepoint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haufe.sharepoint) seems simpler, but I didn't manage to list all folders from a URL with it.

I must confess I don't really understand Sharepoint very much either, though I'm assuming it could behave sorta like a file repository for my purpose. So I will not be offended if someone points out that what I’m trying to do doesn’t make sense.

Anyways, I have an url like `http://intranet/sharedir/Archive/Projects/Customer1` and under it many folders containing subfolders and files.

What I want is, given the URL (like the one above), list all directories and files contained. After that I will iterate over the items and apply the rules I’m interested.

If someone could provide some Python code example or reference would be great.

Comment: Hi I see this question is 2 years old. now I do have same question, can you share your piece of code you used that time?